# Vue.js project structure for two SPA applications with shared components

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I'm starting a project using Vue.js library. Project contains three applications:

- b2c (http://somedomain.com)
- admin (http://admin.somedomain.com)
- shared components between b2c and admin (stores, components, model etc)

How should I set up project structure and webpack configuration to prevent code duplication using shared components. Moreover I would like to use npm run build to produce build\admin and build\b2c and keep building/publishing simple (without additional repositories like nuget etc).

Thanks for providing any reference materials or templates.

Comment: If you need only code share (not personal related things like state, data) between your components, then you can split it on modules and use them in both projects. http://vuejs.org/guide/application.html#Modularization

Comment: @GONG so I understand it should be "how to use webpack question" in that case? Do you have any sample configuration of project spitted to modules b2c, admin with shared components module that can be build using webpack?

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: i'm facing the similar problem.  `defined` css are not applied in `component` of app1 into app2.   what would be webpack config so that  it can ship  with css.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using ES6 modules (you can use webpack's modules for sure, but i prefer this way). For example you have this structure

```
/assets
/-js
/--components
/---shared
/---admin
/---b2c
/--directives
/--stores
/--models
/b2c.js
/admin.js
```

So in your `b2c.js` you need to use it in this way.

```
import Vue from 'Vue';

import component from './components/shared/SomeComponent.vue';

/*or var component = require('./components/shared/SomeComponent.vue'); if you want to use webpack here*/

import b2cOnly   from './components/b2c/SomeComponent.vue';

let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {component, b2cOnly}
});
```

And similar `admin.js`

```
import Vue from 'Vue';

import component from './components/shared/SomeComponent.vue';

import adminOnly   from './components/admin/SomeComponent.vue';

let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {component, adminOnly}
});
```

Then you can easily bundle it with `vue-loader` (or vueify if you using browserify, like i am https://github.com/vuejs/vueify)

http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/start/tutorial.html

Here is an example of `webpack.config.js` from docs

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  // other options ...
  module: {
loaders: [
  {
    // use vue-loader for *.vue files
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue'
  },
  {
    // use babel-loader for *.js files
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel',
    // important: exclude files in node_modules
    // otherwise it's going to be really slow!
    exclude: /node_modules/
  }
]
},
  // if you are using babel-loader directly then
  // the babel config block becomes required.
  babel: {
    presets: ['es2015'],
    plugins: ['transform-runtime']
  }
}
```

Then, you can include yours compiled `admin.js` and `b2c.js` somewhere in your project.